Apply extra classes to a Tailwind selector?
Everytime I use a dark: selector in Tailwind, I also want to apply a transition:
transition-colors duration-1000

Is there a way to target the dark: class and @apply those classes, something like:
.dark {
    @apply transition-colors duration-1000;

The above does not work.
Please note, I do not wish to apply to every element like this:
body * {
    @apply transition-colors duration-1000;
}

Just the ones with the dark class.

Have you tried body .dark *{} ?
